# Range type with Npgsql

Tags: c#, entity-framework, npgsql

I'm reverse engineering a representation of an existing Postgres database with Npgsql and EF Core.  Things seem to at least be mostly in place, except I've noticed that none of my range type columns are present.  This isn't too surprising considering C# has no data type that would be naturally analogous.

It seems that there is some kind of support based on this thread https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/126 and the notes here http://www.npgsql.org/dev/types.html but so far I haven't been able to find any details on how to go about implementing anything.

Edit:
I found the NpgsqlRange type, but I'm getting the error `'NpgsqlRange<int>' which is not supported by current database provider`.  I have the modebuilder set up with `.HasColumnType("int4range")` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Npgsql fully supports PostgreSQL ranges at the ADO.NET level, but the Entity Framework Core provider doesn't include support for this (frankly, nobody's requested it as range usage seems a bit rare). [An issue is already open for this](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/63), I'll try to get this done for 1.2.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the response.  In the meantime, what's the best solution?  Is there a way I can use defaultvalue or computedvalue or something similar to construct a range value when writing to the database?  I actually don't need to read any range types, I just need to be able to write them.  p.s. I have also noticed my enum columns are missing, but hopefully I'll just be able to implement those as strings.

Comment: You always have the option of managing ranges outside of EF Core, i.e. using raw SQL. If you use EF Core to create your tables, you can add SQL to your migrations to alter the table and add the range column, and then you can simply use SQL at save-time to populate the range. Enums unfortunately are even less supported, and things don't look good as considerable changes are required in the core of EF Core (see https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/27)

Comment: The table with my range type is in the middle of an inheritance hierarchy, and has a foreign key which relates to tables both above and below it in the hierarchy.  Is there a better way to write the range data other than making a query after `SaveChanges()` to get a list of all the ids, and then iterating through the list and individually executing update statements where id=id?  Sorry, I'm rather new to working with databases in .NET.

Comment: Yeah, that could be tricky... If you're a bit brave, I'm in the process of adding at least the built-in range types (which would include int4range). Once that's committed (probably today) you can use a CI nuget or build yourself - that would mean you're on an experimental (although generally stable) version.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try when I get a chance.  Thanks.